# VBS to check outlook appointments atendees and send e-mail for those who didn't answer

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I am trying to automate outlook to look up for my appointments and check who are the atendees that didn't answer the invite.

I managed to send myself an email that shows my agenda, but I am struggling to find setup for cheking atendees...

Is there anyone who can point me a direction?

Thanks in advance!

```
'Setup
Const myEmailAddress = "myEmail@email.com"
Const includePrivateDetails = True 
Const howManyDaysToDisplay = 5
Const olCalendarMailFormatDailySchedule = 0
Const olFreeBusyAndSubject = 2
Const olFullDetails = 2 
Const olFolderCalendar = 9

SendCalendar myEmailAddress, Date, (Date + (howManyDaysToDisplay - 1))

Sub SendCalendar(strAdr, datBeg, datEnd) 
Dim olkApp, olkSes, olkCal, olkExp, olkMsg 
Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
Set olkSes = OlkApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
olkSes.Logon olkApp.DefaultProfileName 
Set olkCal = olkSes.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar) 
Set olkExp = olkCal.GetCalendarExporter

With olkExp 
.CalendarDetail = olFreeBusyAndSubject 
.IncludePrivateDetails = includePrivateDetails 
.RestrictToWorkingHours = False 
.StartDate = datBeg 
.EndDate = datEnd 
End With

Set olkMsg = olkExp.ForwardAsICal(olCalendarMailFormatDailySchedule)

With olkMsg 
.To = strAdr 
.Display Change to Send later
End With

'Free memory
Set olkCal = Nothing 
Set olkExp = Nothing 
Set olkMsg = Nothing 
olkSes.Logoff 
Set olkSes = Nothing 
Set olkApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```